# How do I have 'brew install most' use a different ftp address since the current one times out?

Tags: timeout, homebrew

I'd like to install `most` with `brew`.  I've tried recently, but the ftp address is timing out, and I'm not sure how to tell `brew` to use a different location to retrieve the source.

How can tell brew to use a different url when it attempts to download the most-5.0.0a.tar.bz2 lib?

Answer (score 0):

If you type in `brew edit most`, it'll open up a text editor with the url. Editing this and saving the file results in brew installing from the new url.

As you can see in this example, the url for the download location changed accordingly:

```
# changed the url from ftp:// to NOTREALftp://.....
$ brew edit most

$ brew install most
==> Installing most
==> Downloading NOTREALftp://space.mit.edu/pub/davis/most/most-5.0.0a.tar.bz2
curl: (1) Protocol NOTREALftp not supported or disabled in libcurl
Error: Failed to download resource "most"
Download failed: NOTREALftp://space.mit.edu/pub/davis/most/most-5.0.0a.tar.bz2
```